# ASP.NET Odata Web API Composable function issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am building a Service Layer in Web API OData that exposes a file management API. I have a problem with composable functions. Consider the following scenario. Particular files can be accessed in two ways: through an `ID` or through a complex `Path`. My original design concept was to have two URLS:

- `/File({IdAsGuid})`
- `/Repositories({RepositoryName})/Libraries({libName})/Path({path})/api.getFileByName(name={fileName})`

This worked pretty well using the `ODataRoute` attributes. The next step was to support versions, which would use URL's like:

- `/File({IdAsGuid})/Versions({versionNumber})`
- `/Repositories({RepositoryName})/Libraries({libName})/Path({path})/api.getFileByName(name={fileName})/Versions({versionNumber})`

Using an `EntitySet` "Versions" as a path segment was no problem or the first URL. However, OData refused to validate the `EntitySet` used after the function call. The error:

> The segment 'eBesNg.getContentByName' must be the last segment in the 
>   URI because it is one of the following: $ref, $batch, $count, $value, 
>   $metadata, a named media resource, an action, a noncomposable
>   function, an  action import, a noncomposable function import, an
>   operation with void  return type, or an operation import with void
>   return type.

After some research, I realized that the function is defined as follows:

```cs
builder.Namespace = "api";
var function = builder.EntityType<Path>().Function("getFileByName");
function.Parameter<string>("name");
function.ReturnsFromEntitySet<File>("Files");
```

And may additionally require:

```cs
function.IsComposable = true;
```

However, this created a different issue. Now, during the OData validation, I receive a `NullReferenceException`:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>   Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.ODataPathParser.CreatePropertySegment(ODataPathSegment
>   previous, IEdmProperty property, String queryPortion) +205
>   Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.ODataPathParser.CreateNextSegment(String
>   text) +405
>   Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.ODataPathParser.ParsePath(ICollection'1
>   segments) +244
>   Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.ODataPathFactory.BindPath(ICollection'1
>   segments, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration) +96
>   Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.ODataUriParser.ParsePathImplementation()
>   +205

What am I missing? Is it not possible to use functions for navigation *and* continue to navigate on results in OData?

Answer (score 0):

You should properly set the `EntitySetPath` of your function. That is, replace:

```cs
function.ReturnsFromEntitySet<File>("Files");
```

With

```cs
function.ReturnsEntityViaEntitySetPath<File>("bindingParameter/xxx");
```

Here is a complete sample:

```cs
class Path
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public File File { get; set; }
}

class File
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Version> Versions { get; set; }
}

class Version
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.Namespace = "api";
        builder.EntityType<File>();
        var function = builder.EntityType<Path>().Function("getFileByName");
        function.Parameter<string>("name");
        //function.ReturnsFromEntitySet<File>("Files");
        function.ReturnsEntityViaEntitySetPath<File>("bindingParameter/File");
        function.IsComposable = true;
        builder.EntitySet<Path>("Paths");
        builder.EntitySet<Version>("Versions");
        var model = builder.GetEdmModel();

        string path = "Paths('1')/api.getFileByName(name='sd')/Versions('s')";
        var parser = new ODataUriParser(model, new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));
        var pa = parser.ParsePath();
        Console.WriteLine(pa);
    }
}
```